# zeromq pattern for multi client pull receive from one server pushing socket

Tags: zeromq

I want to use zeromq for several clients labeled as 1...n to pull receive from one same socket in server pushing messages containing one field as client id. When server push message labeled 1, only client 1 receives it.

one way is to generate the same number of server sockets for clients to one by one connect, which I think there may be a better solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Publish/Subscribe" pattern and set socket options for filtering messages.

Code for SUB side:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB);
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)
string = socket.recv()
```

Code for PUB side:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
topic = 10001
messagedata = random.randrange(1,215) - 80
socket.send("%d %d" % (topic, messagedata))
```

Examples and pattern describe [here](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html)

**Update**

Another pattern which you may use *Router*-*Req*.
Common idea:
[image]

Examples for python [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:rtreq)

Comment: pub/sub pattern may probably lose messages not suitable here. is there any patterns based on push/pull ?

Comment: @ZFY, May try router/dealer pattern